# How to extract some part of WordPress full source code

Tags: database, mysql, wp-blog-header.php

Is it possible to extract some part of WordPress  like the posting and display of content.

In the posting part all the processes used in posting and updating a content or the posts.

Ihe index process I mean an easy way to view content from the database without going to many process which the website those. For instance 
`www.example.com/wordpress/index.php` should have the power to go direct to the database and get information of the posted content and display it not going tru alot of like

```
//<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

it should be like 

//<?php 
      error_reporting(0);
      require_once("_includes/connection.php");
      require_once("_includes/functions.php"); 
      {
    $msg=$_GET['msg'];
}
?>
<?php find_selected_page(); ?>
<?php $query="Select * from index_post order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,5 ";
$index_post=mysql_query($query);

$query="Select * from freead where cat_id='$sel_page[id]' ";
$freead=mysql_query($query);
?>
```

the above gets information direct from my database instead of checking themes and error before looking content.

Comment: Not sure what is it that you are trying to do. Sure you can directly query the DB, but whats then?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say what you have for `post_content` in database is `$raw_content`. Then what end result displayed by theme (simplified and varies a bit) would roughly be `apply_filters( 'the_content', $raw_content )`.

*Which* filters? Essentially who knows. Quite a few are added by core to handle things like markup and typography adjustments, shortcode processing, and so on. But they can (and do) get added by plugins as well.

Post saving has similar aspects.

It it essentially impractical to try rebuild this process. Either you are happy with raw data or you have to perform WP core load and get the raw stuff through the motions.

Latter *might* be sped up with technique like `SHORTINIT` load, but it's involved to develop and impossible to distribute in public code.